# Resume normal HTML flow after absolutely positioned div element

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to resume normal HTML after an *absolutely* positioned div element? I'm trying to use `particle.js` background in header div on top of which is child element (with some text only). Then from the end of parent div (particle-js div), I'd like normal HTML flow.

```css
#parent {
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}

#child {
  position: relative;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}

#after-parent {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <p>Parent div</p>
</div>
<div id="child">
  <p>child div</p>
</div>
<div id="after-parent">
  <h1>Normal HTML flow after parent div</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap #parent and child inside another relative div e give it the height  https://jsfiddle.net/f6phun8a/2/

```
#parent {
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
#outer {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
}
#child {
  position: relative;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}

#after-parent {
  background-color: blue;
}


<div id="outer">

<div id="parent">
  <p>Parent div</p>
</div>
<div id="child">
  <p>child div</p>
</div>

</div>
<div id="after-parent">
  <h1>Normal HTML flow after parent div</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#flexwrap {
 display:flex;
 flex-direction:column;
}

#parent {
  flex:0 0 200px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}

#child {
  flex:1;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 200px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}

#after-parent {
  flex:1;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="flexwrap">
<div id="parent">
  <p>Parent div</p>
</div>
<div id="child">
  <p>child div</p>
</div>
<div id="after-parent">
  <h1>Normal HTML flow after parent div</h1>
</div>
 </div>
```